# How to convert image Run length Encoded Pixels mask to binary mask and reshape in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing, deep-learning

I have file having EncodedPixels mask of different size

1: I want to convert these EncodedPixels in binary and resize all into 1024 and then again convert in to EncodedPixels.

Explanation:
In file there is image-Mask in Encoded Pixels form, and images have different dimensions (5000x5000, 260x260 etc) So I resize all images in to 1024x1024, Now I want to resize each image-mask according to image 1024x1024.
I my mind there is only one possible solution (might be more available) to resize mask is first we need to convert run length encoding pixel in to binary and then we are able to resize mask easily.

File Link: [link here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ILMwaO7cvzrGrgT0NNFeNgulZ2bG4Axa/view?usp=sharing)

This code will use to resize binary mask.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

pil_image = Image.fromarray(binary_mask)
pil_image = pil_image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.NEAREST)
resized_binary_mask = np.asarray(pil_image)
```

Encoded Pixels Example

```
['6068157 7 6073371 20 6078584 34 6083797 48 6089010 62 6094223 72 6099436 76 6104649 80 

6109862 85 6115075 89 6120288 93 6125501 98 6130714 102 6135927 106 6141140 111 6146354 114 6151567 118 6156780 123 6161993 127 6167206 131 6172419 136 6177632 140 6182845 144 6188058 149 6193271 153 6198484 157 6203697 162 6208910 166 6214124 169 6219337 174 6224550 178 6229763 182 6234976 187 6240189 191 6245402 195 6250615 200 6255828 204 6261041 208 6266254 213 6271467 218 6276680 224 6281893 229 6287107 233 6292320 238 6297533 244 6302746 249 6307959 254 6313172 259 6318385 265 6323598 270 6328811 275 6334024 280 6339237 286 6344450 291 6349663 296 6354877 300 6360090 306 6365303 311 6370516 316 6375729 322 6380942 327 6386155 332 6391368 337 6396581 343 6401794 348 6407007 353 6412220 358 6417433 364 6422647 368 6427860 373 6433073 378 6438286 384 6443499 389 6448712 394 6453925 399 6459138 405 6464351 410 6469564 415 6474777 420 6479990 426  17204187 78 17208797 227 17209412 56 17214025 203 17214637 34 17219253 179 17219862 11 17224481 155 17229709 131 17234937 107 17240165 83 17245393 60 17250621 36 17255849 12']
```

Comment: Hi, You're going to have to provide a better explanation of what you want.  
Please provide an example of the output you are expecting.
Does EncodedPixels mean 24-bit colour depth, run-length-encoded data?
What does 'resize into 1024' mean, resample the image?

Comment: @ChrisCooper  Now I have edit more details